# Copy NSMutableArray to NSArray in iPhone

Tags: ios, nsmutablearray, nsarray

I am copying the contents of the NSMutableArray to NSArray in tableView number of rows in sections area

```
     -(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section{

if ([appDelegate.selectedCalenDAte isEqualToString:@"TODAY"]) {

    return appDelegate.calenderSowArray.count;


}
else if ([appDelegate.selectedCalenDAte isEqualToString:@"THIS WEEK"]) {


   // NSArray*newArr =[NSArray arrayWithArray:testArray];


    NSArray*newArr =[NSArray arrayWithArray:[testArray objectAtIndex:section]];


    return newArr.count;

  }
```

Using above way it does not show any objects in newArray while testArray has two objects.

Comment: How many objects does the object at index `section` of `testArray` have?

Comment: newArray = [testArray mutableCopy];

Comment: @Ramdy Probably not...

Comment: Why copy array? If you need only count just use `NSArray*newArr =[testArray objectAtIndex:section];`

Comment: Why are you using objectAtIndex:section ?? Is it a multidimensional array ??

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
NSArray*newArr =[NSArray arrayWithArray:[testArray objectAtIndex:section]];
```

with

```
NSArray*newArr =[testArray copy];
```

Comment: but i want to copy particular index item

Comment: Then why are you storing it array , why not NSString or Int

Answer (score 0):

```
NSArray *arrt = [testArray copy];
NSArray*newArr =[NSArray arrayWithArray:[arrt objectAtIndex:section]];
```

here u have to first create a copy and after that u can get the data by index at section